# isset isn't working when submitting a form

Tags: php, forms, validation

I want to validate form fields when submitting the form, I use `isset()` to check if the field has a value or not. The problem I face that it returns true if the field has a value of does not !!!!!

here's HTML code

```
<form action="handler.php" method="post">
<label>userName: </label><input type="text" name="fname" /><br/>
</form>
```

and here's php code

```
<?php error_reporting(E_ALL);

if(validateForm()){?>

Welcome <?php echo $_POST["fname"]; ?>.<br />
}

function validateForm(){
     $empty=false;
     $empty=isset($_POST['fname'])?'true':'false';
     echo 'empty>>>>'.$empty;
     return $empty;
 }

?>
```

Comment: "isset — Determine if a variable is set and is not NULL" - $_POST['fname'] *is* set and likely equal to an empty string.

Comment: Also note that `'false'` evaluates to `true`.

Comment: @thetaiko, when I make like this $empty=(isset($_POST['fname'])&&!empty($_POST['fname']))?true:false; return 1 for true value and nothing for false value, how can I return a false value ?

Comment: Return a boolean value (as opposed to a string) and use that in your `if` statement.  Return `true` or `false`, not `'true'` or `'false'`.

Comment: I did like that, please notice the previous comment, when I print the value of false it doesn't print any thing! why ?

Comment: Try `var_dump` instead of `echo`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you want to use is [`empty`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php) :

```
function validateForm(){
     return !empty($_POST['fname']);
}
```

**edit :** removed `isset()` as it wasn't necessary. Thanks to @Julian.

Comment: a simple empty check is enough. no need for both isset and empty.

Answer (score 2):

When your doing an input form, and the input textfield is empty, it's not `NULL`. `isset` checks if it's `NULL` or not. Returns true if not `NULL` and returns false if `NULL`.

I would check if it's empty, using `empty()`. It checks if the variable passed to it is empty or not. Returns true if empty, false if non empty.

Answer (score 1):

use

```
isset($_POST['fname']) && !empty($_POST['fname'])
```

if not sure whats inside `$_POST` ,just print it

```
var_dump($_POST)
```

Comment: You can use the editor features to make format your answer correctly (more available [here](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help)).

Answer (score 1):

Even if the field has no value, it is set with the value of "" (a string with the length 0). If you want to check if there is a value which is usable, either use `empty()` or check the length of the string.